# 3.5mm Audio Splitter - Diminished Quality?

Tags: headphones, monitoring, sound-quality

[image: 3.5mm Audio Splitter]

I have an audio splitter plugged into the headphone jack on my desktop computer.

It splits a single output to 2 different sets of headphones. 1 set is simple in-ear buds and the other is a studio monitor set of cans.

Is splitting a single audio output (LR) into (LR)+(LR)going to reduce the 'listening' quality of the audio in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you mean by 'listening quality'. The earbuds and the studio monitor cans are likely to be of different 'impedance' which will mean that for a set unit output level from the computer, the sound pressure level generated by the diaphragms in the earbuds and studio monitors will be different. You may experience a slight reduction in overall volume by sharing the output, but this can easily be compensated for by increasing the output level from the computer. As far as sound 'quality' is concerned, the only thing that you should expect is a slight level reduction. It is unlikely that you will experience any additional effects other than this.

Comment: Cool - if the 'slight level reduction' is only a volume thing, then that's great.